# Flutter Emulator button stuck on 'Loading'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, ubuntu, dart, android-emulator

I installed flutter and Dart by following the documentation from their site step by step and it's successfully installed, also downloaded to Emulators as shown in photos below. But the button where I choose my device to run the project is stuck on 'Loading...' and 'Loading Devices...'. The operation system am using is Ubuntu 20.04. Here is my  `flutter doctor -v` log through terminal.

```
s@s-K401LB:~$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.22.6 at /home/s/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Framework revision 9b2d32b605 (11 days ago), 2021-01-22 14:36:39 -0800
    • Engine revision 2f0af37152
    • Dart version 2.10.5

⡿^[[ 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/s/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /usr/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_275-8u275-b01-0ubuntu1~20.04-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup
      for detailed instructions).

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • CLT L29 (mobile)            • WCR0218923007245 • android-arm64 • Android
      10 (API 29)
    • sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile) • emulator-5554    • android-x86   • Android
      11 (API 30) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
s@s-K401LB:~$ flutter doctor -v
```

Terminal:
[image: Terminal Flutter Doctor Command]

Android Studio Screenshot that shows the the emulators lists on "Loading...", "Loading Devices":
[image: Android Studio Screenshot]

When I click the green run button:
[image: When I click run button]

When I click on the loading dropdown:
[image]

List of emulators installed:
[image: List of emulators I have installed]

Comment: flutter cannot detect your android studio please check that all step are correct

Comment: this is more of an IDE issue rather than flutter itself. If your IDE can't launch the emulator, there is nothing flutter can do.

Comment: try `adb kill-server` followed by `adb start-server`. Then try to launch the emulator. Or you can run emulator using terminal to see if anything is missing.

Comment: @Doc I can start the emulator manually but the problem is I cannot run the project you can see the message shown on the 3rd picture of my post

Comment: from the 1st pic, it looks like flutter cant find IDE. Use `flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk` and `flutter config --android-studio-dir /path/to/android/studio`. Restart for chages to work. Run `flutter doctor` to see all checked.